# What is changing the textwidth on rust files?

Tags: filetype, textwidth

This seems like a bizarre behavior to me. I've set the `textwidth` to 88, but I've noticed that, when editing a `.rs` file, something sets it to 99. At first I though it must be some plugin or formatting setting, however, this behavior persists when using the `--clean` flag.

I first noticed this in Neovim, but after some testing it seems like it also happens in Vim, which is weirder, since I don't even have any rust-related vim plugins installed.

I also tested files corresponding to other programming languages and this doesn't seem to happen with them (I tried `.py` and `.lua` files).

Does anyone know what is producing this behavior and how I can make my choice of `textwidth` be applied to `.rs` files?

Comment: Is the solution proposed working for you? If so, maybe could you accept the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Yes, it worked great, thank you :) I have just accepted the solution, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is set in the standard `rust.vim` filetype (`$VIM/vim90/ftplugin/rust.vim` assuming you are using vim 9.0).

For rust you can disable it by setting `g:rust_recommended_style` to 0

```
let g:rust_recommended_style=0
```

You can also override it by creating a `~/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/rust.vim` and put the following content:

```
setlocal textwidth=88
```

As mentioned by @romainl more information with `:help ft_rust`